# getText() on input is not returning text

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a confusion regarding getText() in selenium. below given is the web page snippet.

```
 <input checked name=servClass type=radio 
 value="Coach">
  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Economy class <br>
  <input 
  name=servClass type=radio value="Business">
  Business class <br>
 <input 
  name=servClass type=radio value="First">
  First class</font></font></td>
  </tr>
```

I am trying to print the radio button text using the below snippet.

```
 List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements(By.name("servClass"));
 list1.get(1).click();
    for (int i=0;i<=2;i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(list1.get(i).getText());
    }
```

This code doesn't print the texts. Could anyone suggest whats wrong in this?

Comment: The output is correct because the inputs have no "inner text". What value(s) were you expecting to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getText()` returns the innerText held by the element

```
<div id='someid'>
someText
</div>
```

But `input` tag can not hold anything. It is not designed for that purpose. It is called void element.

Input does NOT work this way to use `getText()`

`<input id='someid'> text </input>`

As input holds the text in the value attribute,you need to use `getAttribute("value")`

`<input id='someid' value='text'/>`

Answer (score 3):

for input or textarea you need to use `getAttribute("value")` instead of `getText()` which is used for div, span, etc.