# Element.getText() returns empty string

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The below image shown that we have a field which is pre-populated from the api, and trying to automate that with that I am using the below command where once its available checking if not null.

[image]

```html
<div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline Mui-disabled Mui-disabled MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl" xpath="1"><input aria-invalid="false" disabled="" required="" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input Mui-disabled Mui-disabled" value="America First Credit Union"></div>
```

But getText() is returning empty string, I have checked its the right element and right amount of wait.

```
        return !element.getText().isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

element = input tag

```
  return !element.getAttribute("value")
```

More detail here:
[getText() on input is not returning text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821208/gettext-on-input-is-not-returning-text)